# Angular/Chrome: The pipe 'filter' could not be found

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, filter, pipe

Although this topic appears a few times, but I found the solutions are not satisfying to mine. So I have following:

play.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

import { PlayComponent } from './play.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2SearchPipeModule ],
  declarations: [ PlayComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ PlayComponent ],
  providers:    [ Ng2SearchPipeModule ]
})
export class PlayModule { }
```

play.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'play',
  templateUrl: './play.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './play.component.scss' ]
})
export class PlayComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items = ["Kyle","Eric","Bailey", "Deborah", "Glenn", "Jaco", "Joni", "Gigi"]
  term: string;
}
```

play.component.html:

```
<div>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" >
        <div *ngFor = "let item of items | filter:term" >
          <p>
            {{item}}
          </p>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Now in the Chrome, the error message reads:

```
The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("
    <div>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" >
        <div *ngFor = "le[ERROR ->]t item of items | filter:term" >
          <p>
            {{item}}
"): ng:///ReportsModule/playComponent.html@5:25
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("
    <div>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" >
        <div *ngFor = "le[ERROR ->]t item of items | filter:term" >
          <p>
            {{item}}
"): ng:///ReportsModule/PlayComponent.html@5:25
```

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Can you remove the module from the providers array?

Comment: Did you try adding the `Ng2SearchPipeModule` to the `app.module` (in `imports` array) instead of the `PlayModule`?. Just for validation

Comment: Did both, and same error. Thanks.

Comment: Found out why. The Ng2SearchPipeModule needs to be imported in the root module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add `Ng2SearchPipeModule` to the `Providers` Array.

Your  play.module.ts should be:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';

import { PlayComponent } from './play.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2SearchPipeModule ],
  declarations: [ PlayComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ PlayComponent ]
})
export class PlayModule { }
```

Here is a working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64563253?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: Check the code in the link, it works without any errors.

Comment: Add `Ng2SearchPipeModule` to the imports, just like in the snippet

Comment: In fact, this piece of code is copied from the link, but it does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Found out why. The Ng2SearchPipeModule needs to be imported in the root module.